# Проблема с opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Здравствуйте. На денвере сделал ИМ на движке `opencart` когда переношу на какой-либо домен все работает а именно картинки не хотят показываться, не понимаю в чем дело когда базу данных перенес верно, конфиги настроил правильно, сайт работает а именно картинок нет (ни от товаров, ни системных картинок)

Comment: 1. Переходите на OpenServer.  
2. Проверьте пути, которые ведут к картинкам, с высокой степенью вероятности Вы задали абсолютные пути, а при переносе на сервер изменили иерархию папок или `DOCUMENT_ROOT` сервера.

Comment: А пути как показывает в файрбаге, правильные пути?

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости у вас или не правильные пути или не установлены привилегии на папка для кеша картинок.
установите права на папку `image\cache` 777